# Initializing Object as Value of Dictionary type in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to use object in Dictionary. However I'd love to define object's parameters in declaration of Dictionary itself like:

```
public IDictionary<int,object[]> Whatever {get;set;}
```

is it possible to define params of object here or should i create class before declaring Dictionary itself?

Right now I'm using

```
public class MyObject {
string a;
bool b;
}

public IDictionary<int,MyObject> Whatever {get; set;}
```

Comment: If I understand what you ask, the answer is yes. But using a class for this is a better way. It is more OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type on the `TKey` and `TValue` of `Dictionary`. Special cases where `TKey` is a custom type (like a class), you should ovveride the methods `GetHashCode()` (and `Equals()`) to avoid duplicate items.

In your case, an `int` as a key is ok and you could add a new item like this:

```
Whatever = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();

Whatever.Add(10, new MyObject() { a = "Easy", b = false });
Whatever.Add(20, new MyObject() { a = "Hard", b = true });
Whatever.Add(30, new MyObject() { a = "Difficult", b = false });
```

Comment: In other words, you cannot declare the `IDictionary` and assign elements in the same line, you must set them one by one to provide both `TKey` and `TValue`

Answer (score 0):

As of c# 7 you can like so

```
public class A
{
    public IDictionary<int,(string a, bool b)> Whatever { get; set; }
}
```

And you can create with

```
var a = new A
{
    Whatever = new Dictionary<int,(string a,bool b)>
    {
        { 10, (a:"A",b:true) },
        { 20, (a:"A",b:true) },
        { 30, (a:"A",b:true) }
    }
};
```

You will need to install System.ValueTuple if you want to use it but vs 2017 will suggest this when you add the code.
If you should do this is up to you.